# image on collapse button

Tags: html, css

Can I put an image instead the button to collapse and show the text?

```html
<button class="btn btn-info" style="background-color: #60bf3b; color: white;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fatture">Per D.D.T. e Fatture:</button>
<div id="fatture" class="collapse">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. 
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I do not understand what you want, please explain further.

Comment: if you want in click collapse effect try this one https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to have a background, you could try this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLda16fm/2/))
Just set

```
.btn {
  background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FhZrU6g9seg/maxresdefault.jpg") no-repeat transparent;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And make sure you have these 3 included as well:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Unless you just want an image to function as a button, then you can just do this [image fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLda16fm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<img data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" src="button.png" width="50px">
      <div id="demo" class="collapse">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </div>
```